# Excel 2010 VBA Bug(?) when copying a date using the UK locale to the sheet from a variant array

Tags: vba, date, excel, locale

I work in the US and made a sheet for use in both the US and the UK.  In the US, things work fine.

In the UK, I created a Scripting.Dictionary whose keys were dates (represented as variants so they could be keys in a Scripting.Dictionary).  When the sheet runs in the UK, the format according to the watch viewer has the keys in the correct dd/mm/yyyy format.  This is good.

Then I tried to paste the keys onto the sheet where rng is the range that is simply meant to hold my dates:

```
rng.value = Application.Transpose(data_dict.keys())
```

When I do this, dates that are unambiguously in UK format like 21/12/2014 are represented as such on the sheet.  Good!

On the other hand, when a date could be valid in bot the US and the UK like 08/12/2014 (December 8, 2014), then this code places that date on the sheet as 12/08/2014 (BAD!) which the sheet is now interpreting as August 12, 2014 - as it should in the UK.

Is this a Microsoft bug that is swapping the month and day when a date could be valid in both the US and UK? Is this some kind of obscure feature?!

Here is my non-ideal workaround that gives me the proper date formats in the sheet (non-ideal because iterating like this is slower):

```
i=1
For i = 1 To numDates
    rng.Cells(i, 1) = data_dict.keys()(i - 1)
Next i
```

Comment: You may have some issues here, and might be difficult to resolve... I've tackled this before I think, though... Storing the dates as `Variant` type will probably rely on system locale to determine what they actually *are*, so some dates will appear as strings, others will appear dyslexically (August 8 instead of December 12, etc.) depending on who is running the code in what locale.  Where do they key values come from? Are they originating on the sheet? Or are they constructed in the VBA?

Comment: Dates represented as mm/dd/yyyy are always risky when crossing the Atlantic. As Excel dates are the number of days since 01/01/1900 00:00:00, you can avoid the problem by storing them as Long (if the time is not important) or Double if you need to preserve the time.

Comment: @DavidZemens  The dates are coming by making a call through an API from a third party (Bloomberg) in VBA.  The call to my Bloomberg terminal returns a Time Series of data in the Dictionary container.  So Bloomberg supplies the dates which appear to be correctly in UK locale format.  I see no evidence of any dates being treated as strings.  The watch window for the dictionary indicates #08/12/2014# for example - the # implies that this is being read as a date I believe - correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think that everything is fine in the dictionary and on the sheet - on the sheet, for example when I add 1 to the incorrect 12/08/2014, I get 13/08/2014 implying that it is a date and that the range format is using the UK locale.  Something gets messed up on my first snippet of code: 
rng.value = Application.Transpose(data_dict.keys())

Comment: @grahamj42 - Yes, I believe that would work.  It is an extra step that I will have to be cognizant of unless there is a better solution.  It is just very surprising that dates I have in the dictionary are in the UK locale with a sheet that is in the UK locale would not simply paste the dates as is. I will try casting the variant array to an array of dates and I will also try casting to an array of longs to see what I get.  The longs should definitely work - curious if the dates will.

Comment: OK it looks like everything is OK on the dates in the Keys of the dictionary then.  thanks for clarifying the origin of the dates. An interesting thing happens if I do something like `Const d as Date = #13/1/2014#` while on the US Locale, this *automatically* changes itself to `#1/13/2014#`...

Answer (score 0):

Some date formats are regionally sensitive, others are not.

Regionally sensitive:
`rng.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"`

Not regionally sensitive:
`rng.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"`

The difference appears to be the `;@` at the end of the date format.

Comment: I think that everything is fine in the dictionary and on the sheet - on the sheet, for example when I add 1 to the incorrect 12/08/2014, I get 13/08/2014 implying I that rng.NumberFormat is ok. Something gets messed up on my first snippet of code: rng.value = Application.Transpose(data_dict.keys())